# Why is Kharbranth independent?

Tags: cosmere, stormlight-archive

In the *Stormlight Archive* series, Kharbranth is a city-state independent from the bordering Frostlands. I've read the first book and don't recall anything being mentioned about its history with the Frostlands.

Here's my question: 
Is it known at this point how it gained its independence from the Frostlands? It is small enough on the map in the edition of the book that I read that it appears to just be a city at the edge of the other country. Does it have a strong army and Vorin nationalist identity that led to a war a long time ago, or was it always just a separate place?

Remember to tag spoilers :)

Comment: Frostlands aren't a state, it's just a mostly empty land. Kharbranth is one of remnants (along with Thaylen) of ancient Silver Kingdom of Thalath.

Comment: @Mithoron Is there any sort of government that tries to control it?

Comment: Still, I think origins of Kharbranth and its independence  may be interesting, albeit there may be not much info about it (at least for now).

Comment: Natans would like to rebuild Silver Kingdom in the east Frostlands, but I don't think Thaylens want to go big in mainland, mostly interested in trade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@mithoron](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/35796/mithoron) mentioned, the Frostlands are not a nation state, but merely the region name of the area unclaimed after the dissolution of the Thalath nation of the Silver Kingdoms era.

Kharbranth itself has not claimed any of this land as it itself is located in a natural [lait](https://coppermind.net/wiki/Lait) formed by the cliffs behind the city. According to Brandon's [annotations](https://brandonsanderson.com/annotation-the-way-of-kings-chapter-3/) it was originally a pirate harbour.